# Duplicate codepoints for CJK character elements?

Tags: unicode, cjk

Unicode has codepoints for CJK character elements (sometimes called "radicals", although distinct from the 214 canonical/Kangxi radicals).

**Some of those exist in two places, as two different codepoints.** They look identical or almost identical in fonts that I can see. How come? What's the history there?

For example:

- U+4E5A 乚 and U+2E83 ⺃
- U+20628  and U+2E87 ⺇
- U+5202 刂 and U+2E89 ⺉
- U+5FC4 忄and U+2E96 ⺖

For the first one, there's also U+31DF ㇟ - that's in the range for single CJK strokes.

There's the designated "CJK Radicals Supplement" range at 2E80-2EF4 specifically for those, but most of them can be also found elsewhere in the Unicode.

And those codepoints outside of the radicals supplement range aren't characters that consist of a single element. The shape leaves no doubt - they meant specifically the element itself.

Comment: strange, all the characters on the left column gives me "... is not a valid unicode character" while searching on http://www.fileformat.info. Looking up on https://www.compart.com gives no names for those either. I can't also find them in the database ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

Comment: it's said that the [CJK Unified Ideographs](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_unified_ideographs/index.htm) block has only 2 assigned code points

Comment: Wikipedia thinks it's legit: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B9%9A

Comment: In UnicodeData.txt, there's a gap between 4E00 and 9FEF. Incidentally, that's exactly the CJK range.

Comment: They can be found on the site of the Unicode consortium itself, of course, for example [Unihan data for U+5202](https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=5202&useutf8=true) says U+5202 is "knife; radical number 18". The reason that the unified ideographs range is not in UnicodeData.txt is that it would make UnicodeData.txt a lot bigger, and the data for these characters is all identical anyway, apart from the names.